# Angular2 patchValue push value into array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

Is it It looks like Angular2's [FormGroup.patchValue()](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html#!#patchValue-anchor) doesn't push new elements into an array.

For example something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        animal: [''],
        school: this.formBuilder.group({
            name: [''],
        }),
        students: this.formBuilder.array([this.formBuilder.control('Bob')])
    });

    setTimeout(() => this.form.patchValue({
      animal: 'cat'
      school : {name: 'Fraser'},
      students: ['Bob gets edited', 'This will not show']
    }), 250);

}
```

Will only **update** the first element in "students" but it will not **insert** the second element.

What would I need to do to make it display both elements?

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RFUcj0RupUpHVsuyryUY).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`.patchValue()` only updates the existing `FormArray`, it won't modify the structure of your form model.

> patchValue(value: any[], {onlySelf, emitEvent}?: {onlySelf?: boolean,
>   emitEvent?: boolean}) : void Patches the value of the FormArray. It
>   accepts an array that matches the structure of the control, and will
>   do its best to match the values to the correct controls in the group.
>
> It accepts both super-sets and sub-sets of the array without throwing
>   an error.

You actually need to *push* a new element onto the array in order for it to appear.

```
 this.form.controls['students'].push(new FormControl('This will not show'));
```

This is all in the `FormArray` documentation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormArray-class.html

Comment: How is it possible to know how many form controls to push in advance?

Comment: Good question @kostia. Could you figure that out?

Answer (score 21):

Well, as silentsod said, it is not possible. Currently, I am using below as an alternative:

```
        let controlArray = <FormArray>this.form.controls['apps'];           
        this.list.forEach(app => {
                    const fb = this.buildGroup();
                    fb.patchValue(app);
                    controlArray.push(fb);
            });
```

Angular Team - We need a new function something like PatchArray() that would patch from a collection/object graph. It is a basic use case.

Answer (score 7):

Well, the solution I found out is:

```
this.myForm.controls['array'] = this.formBuilder.array(newArray.map(i => this.formBuilder.group(i)));
```

Comment: how to create dynamic formcontrolname when iterating values through ngFor in angular 4

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you. I have a complex object where my object has an object inside and object inside. sorry for my grammar. but i hope my code will help you

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.descriptifForm = this._fb.group({
      name: 'ad',
      descriptifs: this._fb.array([ this.buildForm() ]),
    });

    this._service.getData().subscribe(res => {
      this.descriptifForm.setControl('descriptifs', this._fb.array(res || []));
    });

  }
buildA(): FormGroup {
    return this._fb.group({
      Id: '',
      Groups: this._fb.array([ this.buildB() ]),
      Title: ''
    });
  }

  buildB(): FormGroup {
    return this._fb.group({
      Id: '',
      Fields: this._fb.array([ this.bbuildC() ]),
      Type: ''
    });
  }

  buildC(): FormGroup {
    return this._fb.group({
      Answers: this._fb.array([ this.buildD() ]),
      Code: '',
    });
  }

  buildD(): FormGroup {
    return this._fb.group({
      Data: ''
    });
  }
```