# patchValue / setValue has not effect on FormGroup

Tags: angular, typescript

I got a `FormGroup`, containing offers, which looks like this:

```
{
  2018-01-01: [
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2}
  ],
  2018-01-02: [
  ]
}
```

So it's `FormGroup` containing `FormArray`s which themselve carry more `FormGroup`s.

Everything is working so far. I save this to my backend and later retrieve that data from there.

However, what's not working is `patchValue` / `setValue`:

```
this._offerService.getFromTo(this.placeId, this._fromDate, this._toDate)
  .subscribe(
    (data) => {
      this.offers = data;
      if (Object.keys(this.offers).length > 0) {
        this.form.patchValue(data);
        console.log(this.form.value);
      }
    }
  );
```

I've `console.log`ed the returned value and to me it looks fine. It contains the correct values. However, for some reason `console.log(this.form.value);` does not show me the updated values from `data` and I can't see a reason why this might be the case.

Any idea why this might not be working?

**Update:**

I also tried the following as suggested in the comments:

```
this.offers = data;
if (Object.keys(this.offers).length > 0) {
  console.log(this.offers);
  for (const k of Object.keys(this.offers)) {
    console.log(this.offers[k]);
    this.form.get(k).patchValue(this.offers[k]);
  }
```

but it's the same.. the form is not getting updated.

---

Here is how the form gets build

The main/parent component creates the `form` where each item is a `FormArray`:

```
  resetCalendarForm() {
    const groups = {};

    this.dates.forEach(d => {
      groups[d] = this._formBuilder.array([]);
    });

    if (Object.keys(groups).length > 0) {
      this.form = this._formBuilder.group(groups);
    }

    this.formValueChange$ = this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((v) => {
      this.dirtyChange.emit(this.form.dirty);
    });

    // This call is important after resetting in order to propagate the 'dirty' state
    this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

The child component gets this `FormArray` passed down:

```xml
  <app-calendar-day *ngFor="let date of dates$ | async" 
                    [formArray]="form.get(date)">
  </app-calendar-day>
```

where, as items get selected, the `formArray` gets expanded by `FormGroup`s representing the elements:

```
  onItemSelected(item) {

    if (item == null) {
      // Do not insert an element
      return;
    }

    const offer = new OfferModel();
    offer.item = item;
    offer.offerDate = this.date;

    this.formArray.push(this._formBuilder.group(offer));
    this.formArray.markAsDirty();

    this.resetMenuSearch();
  }
```

---

This is the data *coming from the server* which I'd expect to be reflected by `this.form` after `patchValue`:

[image]

---

This is `this.form.value` (before and unfortunately *after* `patchValue`):

[image]

Comment: That does not look like `FormGroup` to me + you got duplicated keys.

Comment: @Antoniossss Why's that? The duplicate key was a typo.

Comment: Can you post the part of the code when you create the Form / FormArray?

Comment: We need to see how you create the root FormGroup.  The reason it's not doing anything is most likely because the data you're supplying does fit the correct structure of the root FormGroup.

Comment: @DanielC. I have updated my question with the required code.

Comment: @Willwsharp Please review my update. I am pretty sure the structure should fit. The generated JSON of the `form` submit looks like the JSON which comes back from the server for display. But I'm probably mistaken ..

Comment: @StefanFalk can you show the API response data structure ?

Comment: @StefanFalk AFAIK `patchValue` does not work with FormArrays. You have to iterate over each item in your FormArray call `patchValue` for each item manually.

Comment: @sloth Hm, I actually tried that already. I cannot test it right now but I will do so in the evening. But that was the first thing I tried yesterday but I got the same result. Maybe there's another bug that's causing it which I don't see. I'll let you know in any case. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @StefanFalk `patchValue` will not add new elements to a FormArray. I've run into this problem myself. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/40916084/142637

Comment: @sloth Alright, thank you for the hint then this might be the error after all. I'll check this in a few hours after I got home :)