# Angular2 patchValue JSON data to formArray

Tags: angular, formarray

I have a Json data like this:

`assets/details.json`

```
{
    "name" : "john",
    "age"  : 20,
    "address" : [{
        "main": "address1",
        "sub": "address2"
    },
    {
        "main": "add1",
        "sub": "add2"
    }]
}
```

I want to show those all JSON data in Angular forms with `patchValue`.

I've tried this.

`app.component.ts`

```js
export class AppComponent {
  data: FormGroup

  constructor(private FB: FormBuilder, private service: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.FB.group({
      name: [''],
      age: [''],
      address: this.FB.array([
        this.addAddress()
      ])
    })

    this.getData()

  }

  addAddress(): FormGroup {
    return this.FB.group({
      main: [''],
      sub: [''],
    })
  }

  getData() {
    this.service.getData('../assets/details.json').subscribe((data) => {
      this.data.patchValue({ data })
    }
}
```

And I've design my HTML page like this: 
`app.component.html`

```html
<form [formGroup]="data" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input formControlName="name" type="text" class="form-control col-sm-8">
  <input formControlName="age" type="number" class="form-control col-sm-8">

  <div formArrayName="address" *ngFor="let d of data.get('address').controls; let i = index;">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <input formControlName="main" type="text" class="form-control">
      <input formControlName="sub" type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

But nothing works as I expected. Nothing can fill up to the form. I don't know how to do further.

How can I get all those JSON data in form fields?

Comment: you need to invoke the **patchValue()** method on the *formControl* not the *formGroup*

Comment: I could't get that. Can you explain more ?

Comment: If not, than How can do that in formGroup  ? I'm new to angular.

Comment: Does it work with `this.data.patchValue(data)` instead of `this.data.patchValue({data})` ?

Comment: try patching the control e.g. **this.data.controls.name.patchValue(data.name);** and then the same for the rest

Comment: @BenjaminRussell You can very well use `setValue` or `patchValue` for a FormGroup with an entire object... but here is a FormArray as well, so that won't work, but it would if there wasn't one :)

Comment: Exactly. I've problem with FormArray. How can I put values in FormArray ? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were not to have a `FormArray` in your form, you could just use `this.data.patchValue(data)` (or `setValue` if all properties match), but since you have a formarray, you need to iterate your `address` array in your object and push formgroups to your formarray. Also I see no need to initially create an empty formgroup when building the form, so I have left it out:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.data = this.FB.group({
    name: [''],
    age: [''],
    address: this.FB.array([])
  })
}

get formArr() {
  return this.data.get('address') as FormArray;
}

// ....
this.data.patchValue({name: data.name, age: data.age});
data.address.forEach((x) => {
  this.formArr.push(this.FB.group(x))
});
```

Comment: Okay i'll try It.

Comment: There's a getter, from where we return the address FormArray. I like to shorten it, so for example in template no need to use `let x of data.get('address).controls`, you can just use `formArr.controls` instead, same goes for ts file, but no need for a getter if you don't want one :)

Comment: It worked as properly. Thank you for that. 
But I've a simple problem, it shows an error like that. Could you help me to figure this out, How to solve that ? image link: https://imgur.com/a/wPQj2Ij

Comment: Make sure to clear your FormArray first, as you are only pushing new items when patching

Comment: HttpClient parses your response to an object, but doesn't know what that object contains. I assuuuume here you have not typed your response in your service, which causes the issue. Anyway, there's a section in the httpclient documentation. In short, either use bracket notation or make an interface (interface is my suggestion): https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10):

`patchValue` only updates the existing `FormArray`, it won't modify the structure of your `FormArray`. You have to make sure your `FormArray` is of the right size before patching it, you can also recreate it completely, as shown below:

```ts
this.data.patchValue({ name: data.name, age: data.age });

this.data.controls['address'] = this.FB.array(data.map(address => {
    const group = this.addAddress();
    group.patchValue(address);
    return group ;
}));
```

See this [post for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40916084/angular2-patchvalue-push-value-into-array).

Answer (score 0):

```ts
  this.formCustomer.patchValue({ ...response.data })
   response.data.contactos.forEach(c => {
     this.contactos.push(this.Contact(c))
    });
      
get contactos(): FormArray {
  return <FormArray>this.formCustomer.get("contactos")
      }

Contact(item?:any): FormGroup {
        return this.fb.group({
          tipo: [item?item.tipo:'', [Validators.required]],
          nombre: [item?item.nombre:'', [Validators.required]],
          tel: [item?item.tel:'', [Validators.required]],
          tel_2: [item?item.tel_2:''],
        })
      }
this.formCustomer = this.fb.group({
    contactos: this.fb.array([this.Contact()]),
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

The `getData()` method will work like below:

```
getData() {
    this.service.getData('../assets/details.json').subscribe((_data) => {
      this.data.patchValue(data)
      (this.data as FormGroup).setControl('address', this.fb.array(this.data.address || []);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67670010/edit) to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.