# Why patchValue not working in formArray in angular?

Tags: angular

I create a `formArray` inside `form` in angular.

When I patch object that has `tasks` with values as array, seems that this property is ignore and not set.

as expected, the firstname is changed. but the tasks not. why?

I don't want to catch the specific element and use `setValue` or something similar, I just want to have an object and angular will investigate this object and match the values and the fields.

[The code in stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cczcru?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
import { Component, VERSION } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="profileForm">
      {{ profileForm.value | json }}

      <br /><br /><br />
      <label>
        First Name:
        <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" />
      </label>

      <label>
        Last Name:
        <input type="text" formControlName="lastName" />
      </label>

      <button type="button" (click)="clickme()">clickme</button>
    </form>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(""),
    lastName: new FormControl(""),
    tasks: new FormArray([])
  });

  clickme() {
    this.profileForm.patchValue({
      firstName: "foo",
      tasks: [false, true, false]
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54427292/6444705) can help you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in to the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray):

A FormArray :

```
Tracks the value and validity state of an array of FormControl, FormGroup or FormArray instances.
```

A FormArray is meant to be an array of controls, not of values.
You can only patchValues to existing formControls.

In your situation, if you want to patch `[false, true, false]`, you need to define your tasks FormArray as `tasks: new FormArray([new FormControl(), new FormControl(), new FormControl()])`, so you have 3 controls ready to be populated.

Another solution would be to loop over your array to push a new FormControl with the value `new FormControl(data[x])` for each item.

```
const tasks = [true, false, true];

tasks.forEach(task => {
  this.profileForm.controls.tasks.push(new FormControl(task));
});
```