# Angular 9 Reactive Form; PatchValue of FormGroup with nested FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder, formarray, formgroups

I have a task to maintain the existing project. The app have a FormGroup helper which transform all the data to the FormGroup format. The FormGroup contains nested(4) FormArray and what I want to do is to update all the data of the FormGroup together all the nested FormArray from the root of the FormGroup

```
form: FormGroup

this.form.patchValue(dataToUpdateWithNested4FormArray)
```

Created plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/lKiCc7n2NEckQAXd?preview

plunkr; to see the output need to open console log

I have been struggling this for few days, hope anyone can help,

Thank you!

Comment: @Indraraj26 have you run the plunkr? If you click button `To patch`, only few data got updated and some of second array is not get update. please advice me if I missing something., thanks!

Comment: This is expected you will have to loop over data and push it to formArray

Answer (score 2):

When you has a so complex FormGroup is good use auxiliar functions that help you to create the different formArrays:

```
setToy(data:any=null)
{
   data=data || {toy:null,brand:null}
   return new FormGroup({
     toy:new FormControl(data.toy),
     brand:new FormControl(data.brand)
   })
}
setFriend(data:any=null)
{
   data=data || {name:null,school:null,toys:null}
   return new FormGroup({
       name:new FormControl(data.name),
       school:new FormControl(data.scholl),
       toys:new FormArray(data.toys?data.toys.map(x=>this.setToy(x)):[]
                )
   })
}

setKid(data:any=null){
   data=data ||{name:null,age:0,friends:null}
   return new FormGroup({
      name:new FormControl(data.name),
      age:new FormControl(data.age),
      friends:new FormArray(data.friends?data.friends.map(x=>this.setFriend(x)):[])
   })
}

setForm(data:any=null){
   data=data ||{name:null,age:0,kids:null}
   return new FormGroup({
      name:new FormControl(data.name),
      age:new FormControl(data.age),
      kids:new FormArray(data.kids?data.kids.map(x=>this.setKid(x)):[])
   })
   
}
```

See how you concatenate the functions to get the arrays.

A simple

```
this.form=this.setForm(data)
```

just create a formGroup with your data. Futhermore, I imagine you want to mannage this complex formGroup. As always we manange formArray we can make functions that return the formArrays. Again see hoy one function call to another function

```
getKids(){
   return this.form.get('kids') as FormArray
}
getFriends(index:number){
    return this.getKids().at(index) as FormArray
}
getToys(index1:number,index2:number){
    return this.getFriends(index1).at(index2) as FormArray
}
```

See how you can easy add a new Toy or a new Friend or a new kid

```
addToy(index1:number,index2:number){
    this.getToys(index1,index2).push(this.setToy())
}
addFriend(index:number){
    this.getFriends(index).push(this.setFriend())
}
addKid(){
   this.getKids().push(this.setKid())
}
```

Or remove

```
removeToy(index1:number,index2:number,index3:number){
    this.getToys(index1,index2).removeAt(index3)
}
removeFriend(index1:number,index2:number){
    this.getFriends(index1).removeAt(index2)
}
removeKid(index:number){
   this.getKids().removeAt(index)
}
```

The function that return the formArray help us also to iterate in the .html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    ....
    <div *ngFor="let kid of getKids().controls;let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
        ...
        <div *ngFor="let friend of getFriends(i).controls;let j=index" [formGroupName]="j">
        ...
           <div *ngFor="let toy of getToys(i,j).controls;let k=index" [formGroupName]="k">
             ...
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: haven't try with your answer but looking at your answer I got an idea how to solve my issue, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it fails to patch is because it doesn't create new entries in FormArray elements. To fix this, you can recreate the FormArrays in the FormGroup when patching.

```js
patchFormGroups(formGroup: FormGroup, newData: object) {
  formGroup.patchValue(newData);
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(newData)) {
    const formElem = formGroup.get(key);
    if (formElem instanceof FormArray && Array.isArray(value)) {
      formElem.clear();
      for (let arrElem of value) {
        formElem.push(this.fb.control(arrElem));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40916084/angular2-patchvalue-push-value-into-array

Comment: Thank you for giving the solution, I will give it a try, thanks!