# Patch Value to FormArray Nested within FormArray of FormArray in Angular reactive Forms

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

Here I created dynamic form to Update form value

I have a problem in patch the value to meta array's formController

```
profile:FormGroup;

constructor(public http: HttpClient, private fb: FormBuilder){

    this.profile=this.fb.group({

name: ['', Validators.required],

sections: this.fb.array([this.createDestinationSection()])

 })

}
createDestinationSection() {

return this.fb.group({

 city: [''],

pointsOfInterests: this.fb.array([this.createPointsOfInterests()])

})

}

createPointsOfInterests(){

return this.fb.group({

 meta: this.fb.array([this.createPointOfInterestMeta()])

})
createPointOfInterestMeta(){

return this.fb.group({

type: [''],
})
```

this is the code we  patched the value to  name and city formControll

here **find()** is the method we used to get data for particular id value from database

```
this.find(this.id)
      .subscribe((data) => {

     const destinationSection = this.profile.get('sections') as FormArray;

     destinationSection.clear();
     
     data.sections.forEach((item) => {

      const pointsofInterests = item.pointsOfInterests.map((d) => new FormGroup({

      city: new FormControl(d.city),

      meta:this.fb.array([]),

     }))
  
    destinationSection.push(this.fb.group({

     name: [item.name, Validators.required],

     pointsOfInterests: this.fb.array(pointsofInterests),

     }))

    })
    
 })
```

I have a problem in how we patch the value to meta array;

**Note: html page already developed**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this tutorial helped me

```
https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/setvalue-patchvalue-in-formarray-angular/
```

2nd  forEach loop above example i added

```
var p:FormGroup=this.newPointOfIntrest()
```

then push  p

3rd forEach loop i added

```
var m:FormGroup=this.newMeta()
```

then push m

then it worked me

Answer (score 0):

You've to find how many form controls should be added to the formArray before patching.

This thread might help you.
[Angular2 patchValue push value into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40916084/angular2-patchvalue-push-value-into-array)